# Kick off failed task in airflow

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a dag in airflow in which say there are 10 tasks. All the task are marked with `trigger_rule = all_done`.

In case the 5th task fails the 6th one starts and eventually the dag completes. But post I fix the issue for the 5th task if I want to run that specific task I am not able to do so.

What I tried->

I selected the 5th task and hit clear.

What I was expecting ->
I was expecting only the 5th task to kickoff

What happened ->
The 5th task and the tasks below that got triggered.

How should I able to run only the 5th task without restarting all the tasks below that.

Answer (score 1):

When you hit "Clear" on a task instance, it shows you a model with some extra options. It's described here in [Airflow docs on DAG Runs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dag-run.html#re-run-tasks):

> There are multiple options you can select to re-run -
>
> - Past - All the instances of the task in the runs before the DAG’s most recent data interval
> - Future - All the instances of the task in the runs after the DAG’s most recent data interval
> - Upstream - The upstream tasks in the current DAG
> - Downstream - The downstream tasks in the current DAG
> - Recursive - All the tasks in the child DAGs and parent DAGs
> - Failed - Only the failed tasks in the DAG’s most recent run

Importantly, *Downstream* is selected by default - it means that when you clear 5th task, all tasks below get cleared too, this happened in your case.

But it's enough to uncheck the option to clear 5th task alone.